# CSS color transition across background and text

Tags: html, css

I want to add css color transitioning (non-moving) to backgrounds and text (This sentence is a test sentence.) I know this is possible with CSS/javascript, but I want to do it strictly with CSS/HTML only.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkeQw.png)

In the image above how the yellow transitions to purple with shades in between is what I want to achieve. Is this doable in CSS?

Comment: you are looking for linear-gradient?

Comment: The term for this is "gradient"; searching for that may get you somewhere.

Comment: This site may also help to fine-tune and generate gradients quickly https://cssgradient.io. Simply add the generated background term to the CSS styling of the backgrounds you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation that can be achieved by using the linear-gradient functionality on the background modifier.

Some key values include:

- the gradient angle: `90deg` (horizontally) in this example.
- the colour transition points: `0%` and `100%` (end-to-end) in this example.

```css
    #Box{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgb(250,253,55);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(250,253,55,1) 0%, rgba(128,17,125,1) 100%);
    }
```

```html
<div id = "Box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background-image attribute and set its value as a linear-gradient.

In your case the style should be background-image: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, purple)

Ref. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp